# What's the best control to use to design a outlook like calendar in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, calendar

In one of our project, we would like to have a calendar control that would look like Outlook calender in week mode, meaning one line per day for 7 days at a time. In this calendar we would add resources(i.e. objects) for half-hour or more and those would appear on the calendar.

What would be the best control to use in WPF to design such a control and why ? I was thinking about a simple listview with a rather elaborated item template, but I was wondering if something simplier could also be used.

Thanks

Edit : I forgot to  mention that I will most likely implement some kind of drag and drop to drag resources into the calendar and maybe, if time allow, to move within the calendar itself. However, I don't believe this will make much of a difference in the choice of control since I believe every control can be made droppable.

Edit : Here is what I have so far :

```
         <ItemsControl x:Name="ICPlanification" Grid.Column="1">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                        </Grid>

                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Border Grid.Row="{Binding GridRow}" Grid.RowSpan="{Binding ColSpan}" Grid.Column="{Binding GridCol}" Grid.ColumnSpan="{Binding ColSpan}" CornerRadius="0" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Background="{Binding ColorBackground}" Panel.ZIndex="{Binding ZIndex}">
                                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Description}" ></TextBlock>
                                        </Border>

                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

                            </ItemsControl>
```

I though this would work, but all items are put into the first row and column, making me thing it's impossible to put a grid into the ItemPanal.

And before anyone ask, yes, the GridRol and GridCol variable have the right values in my list.

While looking at some forums, I found something out and it worked!

```
<ItemsControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Path=Column}" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Path=Row}" />
            </Style>
</ItemsControl.Resources
```

Here is the explanation that he gave :

"The problem that everyone is running into the the Grid and the dynamic binding of Row and Column is that the ItemsControl wraps each item in a ContentPresenter so the Grid.Row and Grid.Column binding in the DataTemplate are ignored and since the Grid.Row and Grid.Column properties on the generated ContentPresenter are not set then each item is positioned ontop of each other at column 0, row 0.  You can get around this by setting the below style on the ItemsControl."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your how your DataObjects look.

If you have a `List<Day>[7]` of Days, and each Day has a `List<TimeFrame>[48]` property of the TimeFrames, I would use an `ItemsControl` with the `ItemsPanelTemplate` being a `StackPanel Orientation=Horizontal`, then the `ItemTemplate` being a regular vertical `StackPanel` containing a header for Day of Week, and `ListBox` for the different TimeFrames.

If you simply have a `List<Reminder>` and `Reminders` have `Day` and `Time` properties, than I would do an `ItemsControl` with the `ItemsPanelTemplate` being a `Grid` and the `ItemTemplate` being an object that binds `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` using a Converter to get the correct Day and TimeFrame spot in the Grid

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that. I will have a list of 7 days, with 48 time frame (maybe less since it won't be 24 hours). On each time frame, I will have a list of task (0 or more). Both ideas look good to me, but I'll try the first one, because in fact, my tasks will have more than one time frame (from 1pm to 3pm for example). However, I will cut them into parts to make it look like one big task.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking about it and I will use the second solution, with the grid. I'll use rowSpan for my task with more time frame. I'll have to figure out someway to determine the width of the task in case there are more than one, but I don't think this is much of a problem...

Comment: Actually, I never used an ItemsControls. Do you know a good tutorial for this ? Thanks

Comment: @David Wow, I thought I could find one easily with a quick google search, but I don't see any good ones! Perhaps I'll write one later. An ItemsControl works like an ASP:Repeater. It takes a list and displays all objects within that list using the specified `ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate` to draw each item. The default control used to display the list is a `StackPanel`, however you can overwrite that using `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel`

Comment: Is it possible then a Grid cannot be in an itemPanelTemplate ? When I use StackPanel, I see all my items, However, when I put a grid with many rows and columns, they're all put into the first row and column...

Answer (score 0):

If your project has the budget for external controls and you do not want to spent the time implementing this yourself then I suggest you take a look at Telerik's WPF Controls which include the schedule view control. Here's a [link to a page](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/scheduleview.aspx) that also contains a Demo.

Comment: While it does look cool, I think it might be too expensive for us right now. We don't need that much customization. I do keep it in mind though.